# Webmail system script

Tags: php, mysql, webmail

I am planning to launch a free webmail service at mail(dot)com(dot)es where users can signup and have their free webmail account (for example like www.email.gr). I am looking for a free or low cost webmail system script to install on my website. Do you know any free or low cost scripts which would be suitable for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little biased (because I work on it), but I would recommend [RoundCube](http://roundcube.net/). It's a full feature IMAP client. It doesn't have a user administration, it's a client-only (just like Thunderbird).

With 0.3, we have a [plugin API](http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Plugin_Repository), which makes it easy to extend RoundCube with all kinds of features.

My second recommendation would be [IMP](http://www.horde.org/imp/) or [dIMP](http://www.horde.org/dimp/) (both Horde). IMP has been around for a long time, it's also very extensible. They also have a lot of plugins/addons available.

Answer (score 1):

[Squirrel Mail](http://squirrelmail.org/) is free

Comment: Squirrel Mail is free, however it isn't the client I would go with right away. It's functionality is very simple and limited, but being free it is worth checking out. However if your looking for more complexity and options go with something different, not necessarily free however.

Answer (score 1):

Try These according to your needs :

> Free Opensource :
>      gmailclone.com
>      atmail.org
>   Premium :
>      atmail.com
>      afterlogic webmail pro

Answer (score 0):

[SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org) is in fact functionally very extensive.  The previous comment was naive; that person hasn't ever looked at the plugins available for SquirrelMail - probably the most for any webmail system available.  You name it, there's a plugin for it.  That includes ones to help you manage all your users, which you will probably need.  And you can extend the user management plugin to create a free sign-up page for yourself as well.